# Java swing drawing: how to clear background when animating object

Tags: java, swing

I've written some java swing code that animates some balls in a JPanel using a Timer and some other crap, and it doesn't refresh the background, so it has a streaking effect (I don't know what to call it). How could I go about fixing this? Also, how do I select best answer? Thanks dudes. This is the pertinent code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

     super.paintComponents(g);
             for (Particle b: ballArr){
                  g.setColor(b.getColor());
                  g.fillOval(b.getXCoor(),b.getYCoor(),
                             b.getTheSize(),b.getTheSize());
             }
        }

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                     for (Particle b: ballArr)
                         b.move();
                     setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                     repaint();

                }
```

and the full code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class Ball extends JApplet{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setTitle("And so the ball rolls");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                initContainer(frame);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void initContainer(Container container){

       GraphicsPanel graphicsPanel = new GraphicsPanel();
       MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(graphicsPanel);
       container.add(mainPanel);
       graphicsPanel.startTimer();

    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void init(){
//        initContainer(this);
//    }
}
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class MainPanel extends JPanel {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Particles");
        GraphicsPanel gPanel;

        public MainPanel(GraphicsPanel gPanel){
            this.gPanel = gPanel;
            add(gPanel);
            add(label);
        }
}
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        private ArrayList<Particle> ballArr = new ArrayList<Particle>();
        private String state="p";         //"s"=spiral, "p"=particle
        private int speed=50;             //~20 Hz
        private Timer timer;

        public GraphicsPanel(){
            System.out.println("echo from gpanel");
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,500));
            timer = new Timer(speed, new TimerListener());
            addMouseListener(this);
        }

        public void startTimer(){
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            super.paintComponents(g);
             for (Particle b: ballArr){
                  g.setColor(b.getColor());
                  g.fillOval(b.getXCoor(),b.getYCoor(),
                             b.getTheSize(),b.getTheSize());
             }
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("becho");
            ballArr.add(new Particle(e.getX(), e.getY(), "p"));
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

        class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                 for (Particle b: ballArr)
                     b.move();
                 setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                 repaint();

            }
        }
 }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Particle
{
    private static int instanceCount; {{instanceCount++;}}
    private int z = 11, t=1, u=1;
    private int[] RGB = new int[3];
    private int[] randomizeColor = new int[3];
    private double radius, theta;
    private int x, y, centerX, centerY, size, spiralDirection=1,
                ballSizeLowerBound, ballSizeUpperBound,
                radiusLowerBound, radiusUpperBound,
                mouseInputX, mouseInputY,
                radiusXMultiplier, radiusYMultiplier;
    private Color color;
    private String state;
    private Random random = new Random();
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public Particle(int x, int y, int centerX, int centerY, int radius,
                int theta, int size, Color color){
        this.x=x;this.y=y;this.centerX=centerX;this.centerY=centerY;
        this.radius=radius;this.theta=theta;this.size=size;this.color=color;
    }

    public Particle(int mouseInputX, int mouseInputY, String state){
        this.mouseInputX=mouseInputX;
        this.mouseInputY=mouseInputY;
        this.state=state;
       //randomize color
        RGB[0] = random.nextInt(255);
        RGB[1] = random.nextInt(255);
        RGB[2] = random.nextInt(255);
        randomizeColor[0] = 1+random.nextInt(3);
        randomizeColor[0] = 1+random.nextInt(3);
        randomizeColor[0] = 1+random.nextInt(3);
        centerX=mouseInputX;
        centerY=mouseInputY;
        if (state.equals("s")){ //setup spiral state
            ballSizeLowerBound=5;
            ballSizeUpperBound=18;
            radiusLowerBound=0;
            radiusUpperBound=50;
            radiusXMultiplier=1;
            radiusYMultiplier=1;
        }
        if (state.equals("p")){ //setup particle state
            ballSizeLowerBound = 15;
            ballSizeUpperBound =20 + random.nextInt(15);
            radiusLowerBound = 5;
            radiusUpperBound = 15+ random.nextInt(40);
            radiusXMultiplier=1 + random.nextInt(3);
            radiusYMultiplier=1 + random.nextInt(3);
        }

        size = ballSizeUpperBound-1; //ball size
        radius = radiusUpperBound-1;

        if (instanceCount %2 == 0) // alternate spiral direction
            spiralDirection=-spiralDirection;
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public int getXCoor(){return centerX+x*spiralDirection;}
    public int getYCoor(){return centerY+y;}
    public int getTheSize(){return size;}
    public Color getColor(){return color;}
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void move(){

            //spiral: dr/dt changes at bounds
            if (radius > radiusUpperBound || radius < radiusLowerBound)
                u = -u;

            //spiral shape formula: parametric equation for the
            //polar equation radius = theta
            x = (int) (radius * radiusXMultiplier * Math.cos(theta));
            y = (int) (radius * radiusYMultiplier * Math.sin(theta));

            radius += .3*u;
            theta += .3;

            //ball size formula
            if (size == ballSizeUpperBound || size == ballSizeLowerBound)
                t = -t;
            size += t;

            //ball colors change
            for (int i = 0; i < RGB.length; i++)
                if (RGB[i] >= 250 || RGB[i] <= 3)
                    randomizeColor[i] = -randomizeColor[i];

            RGB[0]+= randomizeColor[0];
            RGB[1]+= randomizeColor[1];
            RGB[2]+= randomizeColor[2];
            color = new Color(RGB[0],RGB[1],RGB[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: To select the best answer, click the check box you see below the answer that was most helpful to you or that you ended up using.  Looks like Reese Moore's answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`super.paintComponents(g);` should be `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: @camickr: To be fair, one cannot accept an answer until a question has been open for 15 minutes.

Comment: I"ll check back in 15 minutes. Based on past history, I'm not too hopeful.

Comment: @camickr: Ahh, just noticed the 0%. Whoops, my bad ;) Though based on the question I think it is a matter of not knowing how.